# Search the frequency of words in the sub pages of a webpage using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I seek help as I am stuck on how to crawl each and every link (pages or sub pages) in a webpage and find the frequency of any word. I used beautiful soup
for scraping but I don't think so I am doing it right. For ex: I need to go to Service now official page > Solutions > View all Solutions. And find the frequency of "Intelligent" in all the links/sub pages under View all Solutions.
Any help would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you :)

**My Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.servicenow.com/solutions-by-category.html"
serviceNow_r = requests.get(url)
sNow_soup = BeautifulSoup(serviceNow_r.text, 'html.parser')

print(sNow_soup.find_all('href',{'class':'cta-list component'}))


for name in sNow_soup.find_all('href',{'class':'cta-list component'}):
    print(name.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need to access the href attribute for every link in the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.servicenow.com/solutions-by-category.html"
serviceNow_r = requests.get(url)
sNow_soup = BeautifulSoup(serviceNow_r.text, 'html.parser')

for anchor in sNow_soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(anchor['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for an `href` tag. This is wrong!

You should search for an `a` tag then get the `href` attribute. This is the url of the linked page.