# Search in Sub-Pages of a Main Webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to search for a `div` with `class = 'class'`, but I need to find all matches in the mainpage as well as in the sub (or children) pages. How can I do this using BeautifulSoup or anything else?

I have found the closest answer in this search
[Search the frequency of words in the sub pages of a webpage using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162993/search-the-frequency-of-words-in-the-sub-pages-of-a-webpage-using-python)
but this method only retrieved partial result, the page of interest has many more subpages. Is there another way of doing this?

My code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
subpages = []
for anchor in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    string = 'https://www.mainpage.nl/'+str(anchor['href'])
    subpages.append(string)
for subpage in subpages:
    try:
        soup_sub = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(subpage).content, 'html.parser')
        promotie = soup_sub.find_all('strong', class_='c-action-banner__subtitle')
        if len(promotie) > 0:
            print(promotie)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about defining a recursive function which  find the links in the page and calls itself ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work?